# Combinatorics questions - How many ways to select balls (answer provided)

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> There are $3n+1$ balls, $n$ are identical and $2n+1$ are different to each
>   other
>
> In how many ways we can choose $n$ balls from the $3n+1$?

**Answer:**

$\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{2n+1}{i}= 2^{2n}$

Can I get an explanation for the answer please?

Comment: The answer gives you the hint.. since n are identical then you only need to calculate ways in which you can select from distinct balls.

Comment: @jeea what's the difference between choosing identical and distinct balls?

Comment: Are you possibly asking for the explanation of the equality within your answer? Because I think the reasoning is quite pretty..

Comment: @fish no just asking how they got to the answer

Answer (score 3):

You can choose between $0$ and $n$ balls from the $2n+1$ different balls, then the rest are from the $n$ identical balls.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that only determining the different ways of selecting $1$, or $2$, or $3$ ....., or $n$ *different* balls will suffice as the remaining gap can be filled by the identical balls. So, it is only required to sum these possibilities up.

Comment: What's the difference between choosing 3 blue balls or  3 different balls (1 red, 1 blue ,1 yellow)

Comment: @Mostfashma Not sure what you mean, but the thing is that there is only one way of choosing any number of identical balls, while there are ${2n+1}\choose i$ ways of choosing $i$ distinct balls from the lot of $2n+1$.

Answer (score 0):

No identical balls/all different: $\binom{2n+1}{n}$. One identical:$\binom{2n+1}{n-1}$. This is because we simply fill the slots with identical balls, without selecting them. If all balls are identical, it's $\binom{2n+1}{0}$. In total it is 
$$
S_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n+1}{k}
$$
EDIT: I first thought that this doesn't exist in closed form, as most partial binomial expression but turns out it does for $2n+1$, but not $2n$ of $2n+2$